# Compile error; running Hello World OpenMP C program in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, mingw, openmp

I'm using the *Eclipse Parallel Tools Platform* trying to run the default **C OpenMP** Hello World project. This is the compile error I get:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc -fopenmp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -fopenmp -o Q3.o "..\\Q3.c" 
gcc -fopenmp -o AS2Q3.exe Q3.o 
gcc: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this, and have not been able to find helpful information on line.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your version of mingw does not include OpenMP. Are you using mingw-w64?

Answer (score 0):

Download [libgomp.spec](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/attachment/31225/0/libgomp.spec) and copy into /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. Hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you, but where would I put it using Windows 7? I'm assuming that's for Linux.